# Kosher food on British Airways Buy on Board

Tags: food-and-drink, british-airways, religion, dietary-restrictions, in-flight-services

British Airways no longer serves a complimentary meal in economy on short haul services, replacing it with  a buy on board service.
When it was complimentary it was possible to order a kosher meal in advance.
Are any of the products sold on the buy on board kosher certified?

On other air lines I have flown, such as AA Delta and Westjet the kosher status was easily found on the website or in the menu.

Comment: Does that answer your question: https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/food-and-drink/special-meals ? It specifically metnions short haul flights too.

Comment: No, that's talking about the complementary business class meal

Comment: The menu apparently can be found [here](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/food-and-drink/short-haul-economy-food-menu?clickpage=resp-information--food-and-drink--short-haul-economy-dining&kmtag=c&ban=||DP|6x1|CTA1|||||||||L2|||||||) from navigating around the link by @TymoteuszPaul. I see no indication of any of it being marked as kosher.

Comment: I know  that BA does not advertise it as kosher, I want to know if any of it is kosher, and do they carry unadvertised kosher food on certain routes (like easyjet on the luton-tlv route)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're flying economy, their ['Buy on Board' menu](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/food-and-drink/short-haul-economy-food-menu) is listed online.

However, it doesn't specifically indicate which, if any are kosher, and presumably that exercise is left up to the reader :/

Indeed, in their FAQ when asked:

**Are there any options for specific dietary requirements?**

All they say is:

> Yes, you will able to find vegetarian and gluten-free options in the
>   M&S on board menu.

Comment: Indeed I tweeted BA about this and the option to order kosher meals apparently does not exist short-haul.

Answer (score 2):

BA sells from M&S so no Kosher food.

Easyjet has kosher bagel with salmon and cottage cheese to buy on board on all routes to and from TLV.

Comment: Kosher beagle?? :-o